# laravel - session expires when change view

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i have a problem with laravel 5.4

when a change the view, the session expires and redirect to login view, and i login again, and redirect to view, but if i access other view, again, redirect to login... Whats wrong with my code?

**propertyController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

     public function index()
    {
        return view('pages.propertyList');
    }

    public function list()
    {
        return view('pages.propertyList');
    }

    public function new()
    {
        return view('pages.propertyForm');
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        return view('pages.propertyList');
    }

    public function remove()
    {
        return view('pages.propertyList');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/property', 'PropertyController@list')->name('propertyList');
Route::get('/property/new', 'PropertyController@new')->name('propertyNew');
Route::get('/property/edit', 'PropertyController@edit')->name('propertyEdit');
```

**navbar.blade.php**

```
  @if (Route::has('login'))
                @if (Auth::check())
                    <li class="active"><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/property') }}">Property</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{Auth::logout()}}">Sair</a></li>
                @else
                     <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                     <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                @endif

        @endif
```

Comment: did change something in the kernel file?

Answer (score 0):

Error here:

```
<li><a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Sair</a></li>
```

It makes logout. Use `url('/logout')` or simple `'/logout'`